# Syntax Error while implementing devise with my ruby on rails appication

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am trying to implement devise in my rails application and I am getting this Syntax error in my header.html.erb

```
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
    Logged in as <strong><%= current.user.email %></strong>.
    <%= link_to 'Edit profile', edit_user_registration_path %>
    <%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to 'Sign up', new_user_registration_path %> | 
    <%= link_to 'Login', new_user_ssession_path %>
<% end %>
```

And this is the error message I am getting:

> compile error
>   /Users/ryanoliver/repos/joyties/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:14:
>   syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' ...roy_user_session_path,
>   method: :delete );@output_buffer.safe...

Greatly Appreciate any help

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a dot (.) between `current` . `email` furthermore you have an extra dot (.) after the closing  tag

```
 Logged in as <strong><%= current.user.email %></strong>. <------
```

should be

```
Logged in as <strong><%= current_user.email %></strong>
```

That is the root of your problem ;)

To make it also a bit more nicer you could have a *My Account* page. To do this you would have something like

`<%= link_to 'My Account', user_path(current_user) %>`

Final output:

```
<% if signed_in? %>
        Logged in as <strong><%= current_user.email %></strong>
        <%= link_to 'Edit profile', edit_user_registration_path %>
        <%= link_to 'My Account', user_path(current_user) %>
        <%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
    <% else %>
        <%= link_to 'Sign up', new_user_registration_path %> | 
        <%= link_to 'Login', new_user_ssession_path %>
    <% end %>
```